# 2D histogram colored by frequency with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have a XY data file with large number of points, which basically represents the X,Y location of object A around the other, object B  placed at 0,0. I would like to obtain a graph showing spatial distibution of A around B using matlab. Although I have a vague idea that I have to use histc, I would appreciate your kind help.

Answer (score -1):

I recently dealt with a similar problem

Interestingly if your points are distributed in a circle and want to have a circular diagram you can read [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rose.html) article.

If you need a regular histogram with bars:
I'm assuming you have a vector for X values and for Y values.
This is what I used.

```
%Create a vector of distances
Distance = sqrt(X.*X +Y.*Y);

%choose number of bins
Bins = 20;

%get max and min
MinD = min(Distance);
MaxD = max(Distance);

%get evenly spaced bins
Increments = (MaxD-MinD)/Bins

%create a vector for the bins
Edges = MinD:Increments:MaxD;

Histo = Histc(Distance,Edges);

Hist(Histo);
shg;
```

Comment: I think the question is asking for a two-dimensional histogramm (with bars reaching into the third dimension). You are throwing away the angular information to create a one-dimensional distribution. That's not the answer, I'm afraid.

Comment: Doesn't answer the OP, but valid point that scalarizing the 2D data might be a reasonable way to simplify things, so +0.